# Updating the data in the form after submitting the form

Tags: angular, api, angular-reactive-forms

After making the checks, I send the form to the API and perform the actions I want. But if I make changes to the form for the second time without refreshing the form screen, it results in an error.

Reason: After registration, the questions in the database have an ID value, but there is no value in my form. Therefore, when I submit a form for the second time, I do not know which ID value will be deleted and updated. But if I refresh the form, the ID values ​​of my answers are filled as they come from the api while my reactive form is being created.

[example of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HikIB.png)

my models

```
import { AnamnezAnswerModel } from "./AnamnezAnswerModel";

export class AnamnezConnectModel {
    patientId:number;
    connectId:number;
    answers:AnamnezAnswerModel;
}

export class AnamnezAnswerModel {
    id:number;
    patientId:number;
    questionId:number;
    answerValue?:boolean;
    answer?:string;
    createDate:Date;
    updateDate:Date;
    connectId:number;
}
```

`

```
onFormSubmit(value: any) {
    let foundAdd = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {
      return res.answerValue == true && res.id == null;
    });
    let foundUpdate = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {
      return res.id != null && res.answerValue == true;
    });
    let foundRemove = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {
      return res.answerValue == false && res.id != null;
    });

    if (foundAdd.length > 0) {
      let valueAdd = new AnamnezConnectModel();
      valueAdd.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
      valueAdd.patientId = this.patient.id;
      valueAdd.answers = foundAdd;
      this.clientService.addAnamnezAnswer(valueAdd).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }

    if (foundUpdate.length > 0) {
      let valueUpdate = new AnamnezConnectModel();
      valueUpdate.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
      valueUpdate.patientId = this.patient.id;
      valueUpdate.answers = foundUpdate;

      this.clientService.updateAnamnezAnswer(valueUpdate).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }

    if (foundRemove.length > 0) {
      let valueRemove = new AnamnezConnectModel();
      valueRemove.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
      valueRemove.patientId = this.patient.id;
      valueRemove.answers = foundRemove;
      this.clientService.deleteAnamnezAnswer(valueRemove).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }
```

`

What do I want ?
Learning the most accurate method of adding, updating and deleting in such dynamic forms!

I'm trying to develop a project with Angular and C# and I'm not a professional. I'm trying to learn :)

**Here I am creating my form.**

```
  newAnswers(questionId: number): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: this.createAnswersId(questionId),
      connectId: new FormControl(this.patient.connectId),
      patientId: new FormControl(this.patient.id),
      createDate: new FormControl(new Date()),
      updateDate: new FormControl(new Date()), // UPDATE DATE AYARLANACAK
      questionId: new FormControl(questionId),
      answerValue: this.createAnswersValue(questionId),
      answer: this.createAnswers(questionId),
    });
  }
```

**and here I am creating the values ​​for my form. but it seems i have code duplication.**
What should be the best approach here?

`

```
createAnswersId(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl(result.id);
    } else {
      return new FormControl(null);
    }
  }

  createAnswers(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl({
        value: result.answer,
        disabled: !result.answerValue,
      });
    } else {
      return new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true });
    }
  }

  createAnswersValue(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl(result.answerValue);
    } else {
      return new FormControl(false);
    }
  }
```

`

Comment: if there's no id, what's the purpose of first submission?

Comment: Hello, when I send without ID, I perceive it as (new record if there is no ID). (if ID exists) update this. I hope I could explain.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my build. I'm starting to think that I need to handle this in the BackEnd :)

Comment: Yup, you could do that in BE, some ORM even have that saveOrUpdate function built in